# Como validar o Google reCaptcha / noCaptcha em PHP?

Tags: php, formulário, validação, captcha, recaptcha

Como envio o tal POST que a Google pede e torno assim meu campo validado?

Comment: Esta resposta é possivelmente relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/60071/23400

Comment: @gustavox é relacionada, mas é um método alternativo (para mim essa validação relacionada `$resposta.success` não funcionou), então criei minha própria validando um `array` **PHP** em vez de um `object` **JSON**. Pode não ter funcionado porque uso CodeIgniter 3, mas é uma forma alternativa e objetiva para quem procura somente validar o reCaptcha. ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você manda o método POST com os dados necessários pra google e **recebe conteúdo em Array PHP** da seguinte maneira:

```
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $response = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=<SUA SITE KEY>&response=" . $captcha . "&remoteip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), TRUE);
```

`g-recaptcha-response` é a variável `$_POST` que seu reCaptcha irá criar.

`file_get_contents(...)` é uma função que executa o arquivo e espera que o arquivo dê resultados como retorno para ela. Nesse caso chamamos um validador da Google através do link e damos valor à ele os valores necessários para operar e ele nos devolve o seguinte **em JSON**:

```
{
  "success": true|false,
  "error-codes": [...]   // optional
}
```

`json_decode('...', TRUE)` transforma o `object` **JSON** em `array` **PHP**. Se o segundo valor (na sintaxe `TRUE`) for `FALSE` receberemos um `object` em vez de `array`.

Você pode validar agora como qualquer outro array em `PHP`:

```
if ($response['success'] == FALSE) {
        // Maldito spammer!
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        // Nice user
        return TRUE;
    }
```

---

Bons estudos! :)

Answer (score 2):

Caso não funcione com `file_get_contents` (como aconteceu no servidor da minha hospedagem). Existe uma biblioteca no github, mas eu implementei com `cURL`. Ficou basicamente assim:

```
# Os parâmetros podem ficar em um array
$vetParametros = array (
    "secret" => "SUA-CHAVE-SECRETA",
    "response" => $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"],
    "remoteip" => $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]
);
# Abre a conexão e informa os parâmetros: URL, método POST, parâmetros e retorno numa string
$curlReCaptcha = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlReCaptcha, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
curl_setopt($curlReCaptcha, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curlReCaptcha, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($vetParametros));
curl_setopt($curlReCaptcha, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
# A resposta é um objeto json em uma string, então só decodificar em um array (true no 2º parâmetro)
$vetResposta = json_decode(curl_exec($curlReCaptcha), true);
# Fecha a conexão
curl_close($curlReCaptcha);
# Analisa o resultado (no caso de erro, pode informar os códigos)
if ($vetResposta["success"]) echo "<p>Captcha OK!</p>\n";
else 
{
    echo "$<p>Problemas:</p>\n";
    foreach ($vetResposta["error-codes"] as $strErro) echo "$strTab<p>Erro: $strErro</p>\n";
}
```

Não vi vantagem em usar a biblioteca, mas, se você quiser ver, há um artigo relacionado em que eu respondi com as duas opções.

Comment: Desculpa, mas funciona, não tenho o projeto rodando no meu server, mas da forma marcada como correta funcionou. Mas obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Nem lembrava que era minha própria resposta, então pode complicar, mas qualquer coisa estamos ai...

Comment: Machado, você deu a resposta neste artigo e outro usuário, Rafael Almeida, deu a resposta em outro artigo sobre o mesmo assunto, ambos com base no `file_get_contents` e mais ou menos há 6 meses.

Acredito que na época funcionou e talvez ainda funcione até hoje. A página do reCAPTCHA diz que tem que ser POST, mas a documentação do Google nem sempre é 100%.

Comment: Até peço desculpas por ter afirmado que não funciona. Vou até editar minha resposta. O importante é trocar informações.

Eu fiz testes da seguinte forma: com `file_get_contents` no servidor da minha hospedagem (Hostmídia). Assim com certeza não funcionou. Qualquer URL invocada na função retornava uma string vazia. Não fazia diferença colocar a chave incorreta etc. Só que talvez a função esteja desativada no servidor.

De qualquer forma, por padrão, a função usa GET (os parâmetros ficam na URL) e usar o POST é um pouco mais segura (por exemplo, não aparece em logs).

Comment: Eu vou fazer mais uns testes. Depois eu encontrei uma dica no help do PHP dizendo como fazer um POST com `file_get_contents`. Vou fazer na minha máquina, pois talvez o meu servidor de hospedagem bloqueie essa função por algum motivo. O principal objetivo é que todos aprendamos um pouco mais! Obrigado!

Comment: CONFORME PROMETIDO: fiz mais testes. Hospedado no meu PC, funciona perfeitamente com `file_get_contents`. Depois descobri porque não funciona na minha hospedagem (Hostmídia): olhando os logs, descobri que está configurado com `allow_url_fopen=0` no PHP.ini. Tentei `ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1)`, mas não adiantou. Em relação à questão se o envio é por GET ou POST: no meu computador, usei o Wireshark para analisar o tráfego, mas não vi problema algum, acho que a função já criptografa tudo antes de enviar. O único problema é ficar em claro no log quando dá algum erro.

Comment: Em outras palavras, se você usa alguma hospedagem que bloqueia o `file_get_contents`, não tem jeito, tem que usar outro código, como o `cURL`. De qualquer forma, como os parâmetros são passados para o PHP na URL, se der qualquer erro ou _warning_, pode ficar gravado no log com sua chave em claro, o que não parece legal.

Comment: OBSERVAÇÃO: se alguém quiser fazer a verificação no JS antes de enviar para o PHP: `if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == "") //Usuário não clicou no reCAPTCHA`

Comment: Ah, interessante, vou procurar na minha máquina o projeto e te retorno mais informações, como você disse a documentação não é 100% e sempre ocorrem empecilhos aos utilizadores quanto à APIs muito grandes. Até mais.