# Validação de ReCaptcha em PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um **form** e dentro dele um ReCaptcha, originário do Google.

```
<form method="post" id="form-ligamos">
        <label>
            <input class="fields text" type="text" name="empresa" value="<?php echo $_POST['empresa']?>" placeholder="Digite o nome da sua empresa">
        </label>            
        <div class="captchaFix">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="SECRET"></div>
        </div>
        <input class="btn-submit btn-submit-call" type="submit" name="fale" value="Solicitar ligação">
        <input class="btn-submit btn-submit-callFixIphone" type="submit" name="fale" value="Me Ligue">
    </form>
```

Ele está dentro da *div* **captchaFix** conforme código.
Como faço para ele validar se o usuário clicou ou não nele antes do usuário ir para o **submit**?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como validar o Google reCaptcha / noCaptcha em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63995/como-validar-o-google-recaptcha-nocaptcha-em-php)

Comment: @LucasCarvalho acredito que são perguntas diferentes. Ele quer saber se o cara resolveu antes de mandar ao PHP.

Comment: @LucasCarvalho minha pergunta é um pouco diferente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode verificar o `g-recaptcha-response` no submit do seu form.

```
function validaCaptcha() {
  if(document.querySelector('#g-recaptcha-response').value == '') {
     alert('Resolva o desafio do captcha para prosseguir!');
     return false;
  }
}
```

> No seu HTML ficaria assim:

```
<form method="post" id="form-ligamos" onsubmit="return validaCaptcha();">
        <label>
            <input class="fields text" type="text" name="empresa" value="<?php echo $_POST['empresa']?>" placeholder="Digite o nome da sua empresa">
        </label>            
        <div class="captchaFix">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="SECRET"></div>
        </div>
        <input class="btn-submit btn-submit-call" type="submit" name="fale" value="Solicitar ligação">
        <input class="btn-submit btn-submit-callFixIphone" type="submit" name="fale" value="Me Ligue">
    </form>
```