# Verificar se o reCAPTCHA foi marcado

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou utilizando um formulário de e-mail em PHP com método POST e utilizo o Google ReCaptcha. Preciso verificar em JavaScript ou jQuery, se o reCAPTCHA foi marcado para só então habilitar o botão de envio.

O código atual:

```
var checado = false;

jQuery("#recaptcha-anchor").each(function(){
 if($(this).prop("checked")=="checked")
   checado=true;
});

if(checado=true){
 return true;
 jQuery('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', false);

}else{
 return false;    
}
```

OBS: Não tenho acesso ao código PHP caso precise ser alterado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tradução da resposta no StackOverflow em inglês:

Google has a call back option for when the checkbox is checked.

> O Google tem um retorno para quando o checkbox está marcado.

Na `div` que faz a chamada do **reCAPTCHA** adicione isto:

`data-callback="nome_da_funcao"`

Vai ficar assim:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="recaptchaCallback" data-sitekey="sua_key"></div>
```

Então você cria sua função:

```
 function recaptchaCallback()
 {
    jQuery('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', false);
 }
```

Quando o **reCAPTCHA** for verificado, e a caixa marcada, o *callback* é acionado e sua função executada.

Você pode acessar a [resposta original em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674946/how-to-check-in-js-that-user-has-checked-the-checkbox-in-google-recaptcha).

**Lembrando** que seu código original possui código depois do `return`, quando você usa o retorno você faz uma saída de sua função, e o código após o `return` fica inacessível, então ele deve vir antes do `return`.

Comment: Com esse retorno já posso ignorar todo o processo de verificação pelo PHP descrito nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59952/como-implementar-recaptcha-do-google-no-meu-site)?

Comment: Não, porque o usuário pode simplesmente remover o script *client-side*. A verificação deve ser feita *server-side* também.