# Erro ao enviar o recaptcha

Tags: php, html

está ocorrendo um erro quando tento enviar um e-mail com reCaptcha

ERRO:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /home/sporalcenter/public_html/envia.php on line 18

Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6LcT8a4UAAAAAJAL2V73sNzlplXwCoV95Nq_qtkj&response=03AOLTBLT5BchbeA_FN9HXT9ikxFgGAaAooyKIwe9Wre-nfKSpDKspGWj0A9HhwDIPFn3K5PR53-FG0IZHgB_k9J3M_mwTK4ttNZm8JOUYkisDnN5BDSHf9yu43QbMLWsNoOslrRyGcUGM-_5XG3UrU2yy7yUhK2pjbJjQWTDEkTYndJMQKWzVSfywsV6u00Cs3ibCMYx1GV1jyBcQLAI8sBTsZD6GIRoJHbxbvM1LMKLIF2728swAC1aBuemJ_haWX-cbFd93V-mcN8YM2BtzJp3Gqo7STBh1_1D1ZKJW94W8SLbDdvRboyYVOLLOVJBAr4TGl8jp7ZgldzZQEzQU7ImI-CMDULALH1y7NIItLEiNsBF1LWCFWw1dGpt3ApcMqwu7d9tXLTUsi11jK9MTBJvLu8vXv9bgJA): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/sporalcenter/public_html/envia.php on line 18
Por favor faça a verificação do captcha abaixo
```

Código envia.php

```php
<?php


$secret_key = '6LcT8a4UAAAAAJAL2V73sNzlplXwCoV95Nq_qtkj';


$recaptcha_response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

if(isset($recaptcha_response)){


    $answer =
        json_decode(
            file_get_contents(
                'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret_key.
                '&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']
            )
        );

    // Se a ação do usuário foi correta executo o restante do meu formulário
    if($answer->success) {

        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
    $assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
        $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];


        // Carrego a classe PHPMailer através do Autoload
        include "phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";

        // Instancio a classe PHPMailer
        $msg = new PHPMailer();

        // Faço todas as configurações de SMTP para o envio da mensagem
        $msg->CharSet = "UTF-8";
        $msg->isSMTP();
        $msg->Host = 'ssl://mail.villageeducacaoinfantil.com.br';
        $msg->SMTPAuth = true;
        $msg->Username = 'servidor@villageeducacaoinfantil.com.br';
        $msg->Password = 'WkJJu336Otimi';
        $msg->Port = 465;
        $msg->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $msg->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
        $msg->AuthType = 'PLAIN';

        //Defino o remetente da mensagem
        $msg->setFrom('servidor@villageeducacaoinfantil.com.br','Formulario de Contato');


        // Defino a mensagem como mensagem de texto (Ou seja não terá formatação HTML)
        $msg->IsHTML(false);

        // Adiciono o destinatário desta mensagem, no caso,
        //minha conta de contatos comerciais.
        $msg->AddAddress('vinicius@otimizamais.com.br', 'vinicius@otimizamais.com.br');

        // Defino o assunto que foi digitado no formulário
        $msg->Subject = "Nome: {$nome} | Telefone: {$telefone} ";
        $msg->msgHTML("<html>De: {$nome}<br>Email: {$email} <br>Telefone: {$telefone} <br> Assunto: {$assunto} <br>Mensagem: {$mensagem}   </html>");
        $msg->addAttachment($meudiretorio.$nomes);
        $msg->AltBody = "De: {$nome}\nEmail: {$email}\nTelefone: {$telefone}\n Assunto: {$assunto}\nMensagem: {$mensagem}";



        // Faço o envio da mensagem
        $enviado = $msg->Send();

        // Limpo todos os registros de destinatários e arquivos
        $msg->ClearAllRecipients();

        // Caso a mensagem seja enviada com sucesso ela retornará sucesso
        // senão, ela retornará o erro ocorrido
        if ($enviado){
            echo "<div align='center'><img src='images/logo-novo.jpg'></div>";
            echo "<h1 class='text-center'>Email enviado com sucesso em breve retornaremos</h1>";
            echo "<div align='center'><a href='index.php'><button class='btn btn-default'>Voltar</button></a></div>";
        }
        else {
            echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.";
            echo "<b>Informações do erro:</b> " . $msg->ErrorInfo;
        }
    }

    // Caso o Captcha não tenha sido validado
    //retorno uma mensagem de erro.
    else {
        echo "Por favor faça a verificação do captcha abaixo";
    }
}

?>
```

Código contato.php

```html
<form action="envia.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome:" required> </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email:" required> </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="telefone" type="number" placeholder="Telefone:" required> </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="assunto" type="text" placeholder="Assunto:" required> </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="mensagem" rows="6" type="text" placeholder="Mensagem:" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcT8a4UAAAAAAhrEt-ljduh-PS8bQ-h36BYpTkL"></div>
    <div align="center">
        <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-meu">Enviar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Relacionada: [Como implementar reCAPTCHA do google no meu site?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102937/3774)

Answer (score 0):

A mensagem de aviso que obteve está bem clara quanto ao motivo:

> Warning: `file_get_contents()`: https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /home/sporalcenter/public_html/envia.php on line 18

Onde diz que seu servidor está configurado com `allow_url_fopen=0`, o que bloqueia o acesso a URLs através da função `file_get_contents`.

Veja a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen):

> **allow_url_fopen `boolean`**
>
> Esta opção ativa o dispositivo URL *fopen wrappers* que permite o acesso a objetos URL como arquivos. São disponibilizados por padrão *wrappers* para acesso de arquivos remotos utilizando os protocolos FTP ou HTTP, e algumas estensões como a `zlib` podem registar *wrappers* adicionais. [sic]

Ou seja, se precisa fazer a requisição com esta função, basta configurar o servidor devidamente. Vale notar que, por questões de segurança, essa propriedade só poderá ser alterada diretamente no php.ini